# Turn off web services in IIS 5 with ftp enabled

Tags: ftp, http, windows-2000, iis

I have enabled FTP using IIS in Windows 2000.  It is just for receiving files from an FTP server to a directory, and is working fine.

I'd like to disable the web component of IIS, but keep this ftp "client" interface working.  Currently, I've just changed settings to "choke" its capabilities, but is there a way to definitively turn HTTP services off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nuke it from orbit would be to stop the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" service and change the start up to Disabled.